# Create a Magento admin user using the API

Tags: web-services, magento, soap

I want to create an admin user for a Magento store using the web services and not having to create it from the adminstrators web site. Is that possible??

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Check out this project: https://github.com/nvahalik/Wiz.

Wiz lets you do many cumbersome tasks (normally done in the Magento Admin Panel) from command line.  Although it isn't a webservice, it allows you to skip the need of logging into the admin panel and clicking around.

BTW, one of these tasks is creating an admin user.

Comment: Nice proyect, but the project I'm doing is in C#.

Answer (score 0):

One approach that takes a bit of custom coding is to create a new API resource that can use the `Mage::getModel('admin/user')` model to create the admin user.

Answer (score 0):

I found it, since I was trying to do all that in C#, here is the simple code to do that:

```
 MagentoService proxy = new MagentoService();
            string sessionId = proxy.login(username, password);
            customerCustomerEntityToCreate ctc = new customerCustomerEntityToCreate();

            ctc.email = email;
            ctc.firstname = firstname;
            ctc.lastname = lastname;
            ctc.password = password;

            proxy.customerCustomerCreate(sessionId, ctc);
```

Answer (score 0):

**First Step**

Bind the new user to a predefined role. A role for the API must be created in System → Web Services → Roles before it can be assigned here.

[Source](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/introduction.html)

---

**Second Step**

Use SOAP v1/v2 or XML-RPC (in my case it's SOAP v1)

Here's the
[Tutorial](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/modules_reference/english/mage_adminhtml/api_user/index) link. You can manage customer till manage order.

Hope this help.